# Custom Attribute missing in the Flat table

Tags: attributes, magento2, custom-attributes

Magento (2.2.4) is not adding my custom attribute with custom source to the flat table. The attribute is not available on the product list page (category). On the product detail page it is being displayed.

```
$catalogEavSetup->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 
'energy_label', array(
    'label' => 'Energielabel',
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'select',
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    'visible_on_front' => true, 
    'source' => 'Company\CustomCatalog\Source\EnergyLabel',
    'apply_to' => null,
    'filterable' => false,
    'attribute_model' => null,
    'backend' => null,
    'table' => null,
    'frontend' => null,
    'frontend_class' => null,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'default' => '',
    'unique' => 0,
    'note' => null,
    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,

));
```

'visible_on_front' and 'used_in_product_listing' are both set to true.
Reindexing did not help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom source model must also implement the following functions:

getFlatColumns(), getFlatIndexes(), getFlatUpdateSelect($store)

If you implement them, than your attribute should be added to the flat table after

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Thankyou - would have been messing around with EAV settings for ages if it were not for this!e